# Can I know a key is copied to the server before it asks me for a password?

Tags: server, ssh, password

To login without password, I use `ssh-copy-id I ~/.ssh/key_name root@server_ip`.

If I don't copy my public key, then each time I use `ssh root@server_ip` I would be asked for my password.

Now I want to create an automated script for checking the installation of Ubuntu instances of our colleagues.

I want to know whether they have configured their Ubuntu correctly or not.

One item I should check is to see if they have copied their public keys to our server, so that they can connect without password.

How can I know it? Is there a way for me to know it?

Comment: @user68186, we're using Ubuntu 22.04 for clients, and Debian bullseye 11 for our servers.

Comment: I tried the answer by @pLumo. It works for me.

Answer (score 1):

Just try ...

```bash
if ssh -o IdentitiesOnly=yes -o BatchMode=yes -i ~/.ssh/key_name -q user@host exit; then
    echo "Connection succesful"
else
    echo "Connection not succesful"
fi
```

- `-o IdentitiesOnly=yes` means that, only the give key is checked
- `-o BatchMode=yes` tells `ssh` not to fall back to a password prompt.
- `-q` make `ssh` not output anything.
- `exit` will let the connection quit immediately

Comment: Thank you for this script. However, when I run it, it freezes in the first line.

Comment: @user68186, yep, I did not copy/paste blindly. I read and understood the code and replaced the parameters.